# Changing Font Size in a button in tkinter when using a text variable

Tags: python, tkinter

I am currently finishing off a simple Tic Tac Toe game using tkinter, The boxes (buttons) which change to either X or O when pressed on. For this I have used a function for when the button is pressed which changes the text in the button using the text variable as shown below:

```
T1text=Tk.StringVar()
T1=Tk.Button(nac, textvariable=T1text, width="25", height="12" , bg="red", command=updateT1)
T1.grid(row=1, column=0)
T1text.set("")
```

This section is the button being created and creating the variable "T1text" (top 1) which will be used to change the text in the button to either O or an X, as you can see I set T1text to "" first, here is the change function:

```
if T1taken==1:
    print("space taken")
elif player=="X":
    T1text.set("X")
    player="O"
    playerText.set(player)
elif player=="O":
    T1text.set("O")
    player="X"
    playerText.set(player)
```

This changes the text in T1text to X or O.

I need to be able to set the letter X or O to a bigger size as it is too small to see in the bigger boxes.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
T1text=Tk.StringVar()
T1=Tk.Button(nac, textvariable=T1text, font=("Helvetica", 70), width="25", height="12" , bg="red", command=updateT1)
T1.grid(row=1, column=0)
T1text.set("")
```

this creates a logic error and makes the box massive that I can even see the other boxes and they are off the screen.

I have no idea what else I could try, any help would be much appreciated.

Thank You very much!

Comment: That's just because 70 is very big surely? Try something smaller and experiment till you get the right size.

Answer (score 0):

Few things to note:

- No need to use width and height option when using custom sized fonts because width and height varies with the font
- Don't set default value to empty string, rather set it to string containing a two space
- The size of the font is too big. Decrease it.

I recommend to change the size of 70 to 30.
The main point in your code is not t use width and height options.
Use `T1text.set("  ")` rather than `T1text.set("")` so there will not too much difference of size when changing text.

Here is an example code:

```
import tkinter as Tk
root = Tk.Tk()

T1text = Tk.StringVar()
T1 = Tk.Button(root, textvariable = T1text,font = ("Helvetica", 30) ,bg="red")
T1.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
T1text.set("  ")

root.mainloop()
```

Here is another example code that changes the text on click:

```
import tkinter as Tk
root = Tk.Tk()
def upd():
    print(str(T1text.get()))
    T1text.set("O" if str(T1text.get()) == "X" or str(T1text.get()) == "  " else "X")
T1text = Tk.StringVar()
T1 = Tk.Button(root, textvariable = T1text,font = ("Helvetica", 30) ,bg="red",command=upd)
T1.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
T1text.set("  ")

root.mainloop()
```

<sup>*You can change the size of font as smaller or larger you want!*</sup>